# JavaScript framework for drawing chart

Tags: javascript, charts

Which open source JavaScript framework for drawing chart is better, in regards to:

1. Being small and easy to learn
2. Having good documentation
3. Having easy to use API (just giving data and position should be enough, unlike [this one](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/area.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try:

> http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

One of my favourites.

Comment: i've used them in quite several projects and they are fun to use and render very nicely, got only good feedback about it

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for basic things like line charts or bar graphs, check out [Flot.js](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). It's easy to learn and use but not super flexible.

Answer (score 0):

[jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/), if the jquery overhead is not an issue. The [examples](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html) page shows how simple graphs can be defined in a single line of code. Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL version 2 licenses.

Otherwise, google for "best javascript chart libraries" and you will find many articles that introduce and compare some of the most popular solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but 
[Google's Chart API](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/chart/) is pretty cool and easy to use.

And here is other [20 Best JavaScript Charting and Plotting Libraries](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/chart/20-best-javascript-charting-and-plotting-libraries/)

Comment: it is cool  , but  i can`t use it , it need connecting internet